# What's the equivalent of Jersey Restful web service(Java) in C#?

Tags: c#, java, rest, jersey

I'm transferring a java back end into a C# one.

It uses jersey restful web service, so what's the equivalent in C#.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Good question, Stupid people voted down, thank you for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's even better option built into Visual Studio if you're using it. Its called Web API and it provides flexible options and is quite easy to learn

[Check out the following](http://www.asp.net/web-api)